# Codeigniter Ajax Jquery form submission

Tags: codeigniter, jquery

I have been around numerous tutorials on AJAX a CodeIgniter but I can't seem to get this to work. I am trying to submit a form which adds a product to a cart.

Here is the controller part:

```
public function addtocart($page = 'orcamento')
{
    ...
    // ADD TO CART
    $idprod=$this->input->post("id",TRUE);
    $quant=$this->input->post("quant",TRUE);
    $prodname=$this->input->post("prodname",TRUE);

    $addtocart = array(
        'id'      => $idprod,
        'qty'     => $quant,
        'price'   => 1,
        'name'    => $prodname
        );

    $this->cart->insert($addtocart);
```

The view:

```
<?php       
    $attributes = array('id' => 'flor'.$florestais_total_count);
    echo form_open('orcamento/addtocart', $attributes); 
?>
<span class="prod_list_quant_title">
    <?php echo lang('orc_quantidade'); ?>
</span>
<input type="text" name="quant" id="quant" class="prod_list_quant_input" value="" />
<input name="id" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $flor->idprodutos; ?>" style="border:0;" />
<input name="prodname" type="hidden" value="<?php $this->General_model->getLangString($flor->name,$lang); ?>" style="border:0;" />
<div class="prod_list_quant_add" onclick="addtocart('flor<?php echo $florestais_total_count; ?>')">
    <span class="text_quant_add"><?php echo lang('orc_btn_add'); ?></span>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

And also the function addtocart:

```
function addtocart(formid)
{
    var pid=$c("form#"+formid).children("input[name='id']").val();
    var pquant=$c("form#"+formid).children("input[name='quant']").val();
    var pname=$c("form#"+formid).children("input[name='prodname']").val();

    $c.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>orcamento/addtocart",
            dataType: "json",
            data: "id="+pid+"&qty="+pquant&"name="+pname,
            cache:false,
            success: function() {
            }  
        });
        return false;
    }
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

try this instead of `$c.ajax`:

```
$.post("<?php echo base_url(); ?>orcamento/addtocart",$("#"+formid).serialize());
```

and see what happens next.

Answer (score 0):

I got it! This is the answer:

```
function addtocart(formid)
{
    $c.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>orcamento/addtocart",
        data : $c("form#"+formid).serialize(),
        success : function(data) {
                // Show OK message
                alert('ok');
        },
        error: function(error){
                // Show error message
                alert('error');
        }
        });
    return false;
}
```

Now i just need to update the product list on the view without refreshing the whole thing...

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a similar issue. Through some testing, I found the jquery calls treat the CI urls similarly to things like CSS. Try removing the base_url echo and see where that lands you.